# Running in docker receive "The 'ClientId' option must be provided"

Tags: docker, microsoft-identity-web

ASP.NET with Microsoft-identity-web. If run webapp locally using dotnet app.dll everything is ok, but if package into an image and run in docker or kubernetes, each request will occur error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.ArgumentNullException: IDW10106: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.
     at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MergedOptionsValidation.Validate(MergedOptions options)
     at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppInternal>b__3(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptionsMonitor'1 mergedOptionsMonitor, IOptionsMonitor'1 msIdOptionsMonitor, IOptions'1 msIdOptions)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions'5.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory'1.Create(String name)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor'1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
     at System.Lazy'1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at System.Lazy'1.CreateValue()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
 "AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "xxx",
"TenantId": "xxx",
"ClientId": "xxx",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"ClientSecret": "xxx",
"ClientCertificates": []
 },
 "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
   }
},
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "MicrosoftGraph": {
"BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
"Scopes": "user.read"
 }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY ./apprelease /home/app
```

Comment: Where you able to get this working?